# Why NOT NULL constraint can be added only in COLUMN LEVEL and ALTER LEVEL why can't we add in TABLE LEVEL?

Tags: sql, constraints, notnull

I tried using alter command and it will be like
 ALTER TABLE  MODIFY   NOT NULL; and its working 
SO why cann't we add in table level like (CREATE TABLE  (COL1 DATATYPE(SIZE),COL2 DATATYPE(SIZE), CONSTRAINT TN_COL1_NN NOT NULL(COL1));?

Comment: That is what the `NOT NULL` constraint means.  Columns can have `NULL` values.  There is no such thing as a "NULL" table.

Comment: you can assume that a table has NOT NULL attribute by definition, as it may have no rows at all :P anyway, such concept doesnt make much sense

Comment: What i meant to say is for example primary key constraint can be added in three levels (COLUMN,TABLE AND ALTER).similarly we can add ALL rest of  the constraints in three level why can't we add NOT NULL?

Comment: we can  ADD through CREATE TABLE AND ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME MODIFY ...!

Comment: `NOT NULL` is a *column constraint*. *Some* constraint types are available as both column constraints or as table constraints and so there may be multiple syntaxes that create similar objects. But `not null` doesn't make *sense* as a table constraint so can only be added as a column constraint

Comment: See [Column and Table Constraints](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189862(v=sql.105).aspx#Anchor_1)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am using **Oracle** ..!

Comment: This is a valid question. Since is closed, I'll post my answer here: `NULL`/`NOT NULL` are **not** constraints. They are **data type definition**. A column declared as `CHAR(10) NOT NULL` is of the *type* 'character not nullable'. You can can verify this with the system metadata views, there is **no** constraint added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What i meant to say is for example primary key constraint can be added in three levels (COLUMN,TABLE AND ALTER).similarly we can add ALL rest of the constraints in three level why can't we add NOT NULL?

I think what you are asking is how you can specify `NULL` or `NOT NULL` constraint on a column when you modify or create a table schema. The answer is you can.

```
-- when you define/create the table
CREATE TABLE MyTable (Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)

-- when you add a new column to an existing table
ALTER MyTable ADD Title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL

-- when you alter an existing column on an existing table
ALTER MyTable ALTER COLUMN Title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
```

If you want to allow nulls in any of the above remove the word `NOT`.

Comment: First i would like thank for your answer but can you give clarity for why can't  we add NOT NULL constraint in Table level.

Comment: @srikanth - What would you expect from a null table level constraint? What do you think that would do?